# Is a bandpass filter followed by a pointwise squaring considered a linear operation?

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, image-processing

Hello just had a quick question, would applying a bandpass filter to an image,and then doing a pointwise squaring of the image be considered a linear operation? if its possible to please provide an explanation that would be amazing!

Comment: Please use more math.

Comment: I think what @amsmath means by that is, please give context about the relationship between *bandpass*, *pointwise squaring*, etc.; if you contribute that knowledge, then we will contribute the mathematical knowledge.

Comment: Dunno, I'll just ask my bosses.

Comment: so the bandpass filter when it is applied to an image it produces both negative and positive values, thus i want to apply a pointwise squaring to each value in order to remove the negative ones and still maintain their magnitude, but i am wondering would this still be considered a linear operation and thus still remain in the realm of linear shift invariant systems

Comment: Squaring a signal is definitely not a linear operation : if I multiply the signal by $a$, the squared signal is multiplied by $a^2$.

Comment: @JeanMarie That isn't sufficient. If the signal were strictly positive then pointwise square root followed by pointwise square is clearly linear.

Comment: oh i see, so in this case taking the pointwise square is not linear since we're squaring each result and thus multiplying the function by itself, then its no longer in the LSI system, since now it would be f(x) -> [g(x)]^2

Comment: well applying a bandpass would result in negative and positive values so isnt Jean Marie correct in this case? @adfriedman

Comment: @eddielong It doesn't necessarily result in negative and positive values. A band pass applied to $f(x)=\sin(x)+1 \geq 0$ would not be negative if the filter were centered about $0$. I am trying to emphasize that the fact a band pass filter is a linear operator is important, otherwise you could have two non-linear operators that are linear when combined.

Comment: i see! that makes intuitive sense. Since it is a linear operator then the combination is not linear because the other component the squaring is not linear, if we did for example two squaring operations then it would be linear since both are non-linear operators, correct? Thank you so very much for all your help btw, this stuff is a bit tough for me but this has been great!

Comment: @eddielong not exactly. I'm not saying that two non-linear operators are linear, but that they **could be**. If you square and then square again, then applying the same argument as in my answer, it would require for all $x,y$
$$((x+y)^2)^2 = (x^2+y^2)^2 = (x^2)^2 + (y^2)^2$$
which would imply $x=y=0$. So that would **not** be a linear operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A band pass filter is a linear operator, so in order for both steps to be linear you would need for pointwise squaring to be a linear operator on the range of the band pass filter (i.e., all values mapped to by the band pass filter). In order for pointwise squaring to be a linear operator it would be linear pointwise, requiring $(x+y)^2 = x^2+y^2$ for all $x$, $y$ possible as matrix elements resulting from a band pass filter. This is only true if $x=y=0$, i.e., if the band pass maps every signal to zero.

Comment: makes alot of sense, thank you so much! so in this case its not a linear operator as the x and y values differ :D